# Create Artisan command with option that must specify a value

Tags: php, laravel, command-line-arguments, laravel-artisan

[Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#options) says (emphasis mine):

> If the user ***must*** specify a value for an option, you should suffix the option name with a `=` sign…

But then goes on to say:

> If the option is not specified when invoking the command, its value will be `null`…

Which suggests that "must" doesn't mean what I think it means. And indeed that is the case. A simple command with a signature like this:

```php
protected $signature = "mycommand {-t|test=}";
```

Will run just fine when called like `artisan mycommand -t`. And what's worse is that if you specify a default value, it isn't applied in this case.

```php
protected $signature = "mycommand {-t|test=42}";
```

When running `artisan mycommand`, `$this->option('test')` will give you a value of 42, but when run as `artisan mycommand -t` it gives a value of `null`.

So, is there a way to require that a user must (actually) specify a value for a given option, if it's present on the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poking around [the Laravel code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Console/Parser.php#L117), I confirmed that there is no way to have a truly "required" value. Although Symfony [does provide](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/input.html#using-command-options) for required values, Laravel doesn't use this capability. Instead the options are all created as optional, so I will have to write my own parser...

This was fairly straightforward; I had to write a custom parser class to override the `Illuminate\Console\Parser::parseOption()` method, and then override `Illuminate\Console\Command::configureUsingFluentDefinition()` to use that new class.

I elected to create a new option type, rather than change the behaviour of any existing command options. So now I declare my signature like this when I want to force a value:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Console\Command;

class MyCommand extends Command
{
    /** @var string The double == means a required value */
    protected $signature = "mycommand {--t|test==}";

    ...
}
```

Attempting to run `artisan mycommand -t` will now throw a `Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException` with a message of "**The --test option requires a value.**" This also works for array options (`--t==*`) and/or options with default values (`--t==42` or `--t==*42`.)

Here's the code for the new parser class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Parser as BaseParser;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;

class Parser extends BaseParser
{
    protected static function parseOption($token): InputOption
    {
        [$mytoken, $description] = static::extractDescription($token);

        $matches = preg_split("/\\s*\\|\\s*/", $mytoken, 2);

        if (isset($matches[1])) {
            $shortcut = $matches[0];
            $mytoken = $matches[1];
        } else {
            $shortcut = null;
        }

        switch (true) {
            case str_ends_with($mytoken, "=="):
                return new InputOption(
                    trim($mytoken, "="),
                    $shortcut,
                    InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED,
                    $description
                );
            case str_ends_with($mytoken, "==*"):
                return new InputOption(
                    trim($mytoken, "=*"),
                    $shortcut,
                    InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED | InputOption::VALUE_IS_ARRAY,
                    $description
                );
            case preg_match("/(.+)==\*(.+)/", $mytoken, $matches):
                return new InputOption(
                    $matches[1],
                    $shortcut,
                    InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED | InputOption::VALUE_IS_ARRAY,
                    $description,
                    preg_split('/,\s?/', $matches[2])
                );
            case preg_match("/(.+)==(.+)/", $mytoken, $matches):
                return new InputOption(
                    $matches[1],
                    $shortcut,
                    InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED,
                    $description,
                    $matches[2]
                );
            default:
                // no == here, fall back to the standard parser
                return parent::parseOption($token);
        }
    }
}
```

And the new command class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Command as BaseCommand;

class Command extends BaseCommand
{
    /**
     * Overriding the Laravel parser so we can have required arguments
     *
     * @inheritdoc
     * @throws ReflectionException
     */
    protected function configureUsingFluentDefinition(): void
    {
        // using our parser here
        [$name, $arguments, $options] = Parser::parse($this->signature);

        // need to call the great-grandparent constructor here; probably
        // could have hard-coded to Symfony, but better safe than sorry
        $reflectionMethod = new ReflectionMethod(
            get_parent_class(BaseCommand::class),
            "__construct"
        );
        $reflectionMethod->invoke($this, $name);

        $this->getDefinition()->addArguments($arguments);
        $this->getDefinition()->addOptions($options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. Looks cool. But what is the `ReflectionMethod` part? Can you please provide the final working solution you have?